# Como contar registros na relação OneToMane retornando zero quando não houver correspondência

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, count

Amigos,

estou tentando fazer um app para controle de investimentos em ações. No DB deste app tenho a tabela carteira e a tabela ativo. Preciso fazer um select que me retorne as carteiras ativas e a quantidade de papeis(ações) que cada carteira tem. Ocorre que a carteira pode estar ativa mas ainda não conter nenhuma ação.

fiz a seguinte consulta:

```
select c.codigo, c.nome, c.inicio, COUNT(a.codigobovespa) as qtde_papeis
from carteira c inner join ativo a
on c.codigo=a.carteira
where c.ativa = 'S'
group by c.codigo, c.nome, c.inicio
```

Todavia apesar da consulta montar os campos direitinho, ela somente retorna uma carteira, mesmo ativa, se ela contiver um correspondente na tabela ativo. E eu preciso que aparece todas e quantidade zero quando nao houver ativo correspondente na tabela ativo.

Alguem pode me ajudar nessa?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Como você quer trazer os dados da tabela `carteira` mesmo que não existam dados na tabela `ativo`, você deve utilizar o `left join`:

[image: A representa a tabela carteira enquanto B representa a tabela ativo]

- **A** = Carteira
- **B** = Ativo

---

Logo sua query ficará da seguinte maneira:

```
select c.codigo
     , c.nome
     , c.inicio
     , count(a.codigobovespa) as qtde_papeis
  from carteira c left join ativo a
    on c.codigo = a.carteira
 where c.ativa = 'S'
 group by c.codigo, c.nome, c.inicio
```

> Veja online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/47e794/6

---

Caso queira compreender melhor sobre join em SQL, recomendo muito a leitura da seguinte pergunta/resposta: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)